# Remove&Create VS Search&Update Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

1. Say I have [**this HTML mockup**](http://jsbin.com/udoxuv/3).
2. Say I need to update the information (Value header) in a regular interval, 1s. That should be done for every table in the mockup. I get the data via websocket in JSON format.

The **question** is: What is the best way to update the data in the tables? Removing the content and creating new DOM elements or searching the DOM elements and updating their values?

Comment: As with every performance question, it's going to depend. The only way to know reliably is to [try it for yourself](http://jsperf.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing selector accesses via jquery. [**I updated the HTML mockup**](http://jsbin.com/udoxuv/12/edit) because I forgot to mention that I could easily identify the values I have to update by a class selector. I had this class selector before but then simplified the mockup to make a question in here. [**A performance test**](http://jsperf.com/testing-remove-create-vs-searching-update/4) is done here. **Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14979177/2064818) answer doesn't apply to my case is totally valid.**

The valid code to update the values is:

```
$('.values').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() != "&nbsp;") {
    $(this).text("UP1");
  }
});
```

You could also narrow the jquery lookup to specific table (example table from the HTML mockup):

```
$('#tableWrap_group_1 .values').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html() != "&nbsp;") {
    $(this).text("UP1");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way would be to keep references to DOM elements in js - create each  with

`tableRefs[row][col]=document.createElement('td');`

and keep a reference to it. Then just update through

```
tableRefs[row][col].innerHTML='yourDataHere';
```

I wouldn't worry about performance unless you are planning to run on ancient/low performance devices and your data is around 100 rows.